# How do you get "Bait" in Far Cry New Dawn?

Tags: far-cry-new-dawn

When I kill animals I get "Meat" and "Skins" in game. In previous Far Cry games (up to the previous entry Far Cry 5) this meant bait was auto-added to your "throwables" menu. It could then be equipped by scrolling up or down with the mouse wheel.

Is this option just not there anymore, or is it hidden behind a "base upgrade"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can craft bait using 1 meat and 1 Yucca** (the orange plant).

After crafting, it will appear in your inventory and quick menu.

[image: Far Cry New Dawn bait item crafting]

> Consumables can be crafted in the:
>
> - INVENTORY, by highlighting the item and holding down the assigned button.
> - WEAPON WHEEL, by highlighting the item on the left of the screen and holding down the assigned button.

<sup>sources: [orcz.com](http://orcz.com/Far_Cry_New_Dawn:_Bait), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/farcry/comments/aqzit6/how_do_you_throw_bait_in_this_game_in_far_cry_new/) and [Ubisoft support](https://support.ubi.com/fi-FI/Faqs/000040734)</sup>

Comment: where is the crafting menu?

Comment: I edited it to my answer.

Comment: Dank je @joachim